# RXJS net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs

I am trying to make 3000 api calls all at once with rxjs.

I have read and researched all over the place but I cannot find any way of doing it without getting this net error.

Comment: 300 api calls will leak your memory resources!

Comment: Its not for a shippable product